# IOS apps that will support both RTL and LTR in one application which can be changed dynamically

Tags: ios, right-to-left

I am confused to design  the application in **RTL** as well as **LTR**

**1:** I have created two story board for Arabic and normal home for all languages except Arabic.

**2:** I have tried to change the app language in application but it will require restart the application so how can i restart ?? .

**3:** ios9 provide new feature but at time only one language we have to select from `project->edit scheme-> language` but **I need two language support English as well as Arabic at one application which can be change dynamically**.

Please give me your suggestions. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the user language preference. Acc. to the language specified you can display the data in the specified language. You don't need to create separate storyboards for each languages. Just dynamically retrieve the language specified and display the data accordingly.

Comment: hi, actually i am doing same but the problem is that for arabic i have to change layout also like left to right -> right to left so how can i do that.

Comment: If you use leading/trailing constraints (not left/right) then the storyboard will automatically flip based on the current locale

Comment: Hi sir, i have set the arabic in applanguage and again load the (- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {})  but not cahnges occur but again run then it will effect so my question is how to restart the application